# Use the JOIN command with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery and I get this query to work:

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, suppliers.supplier_name, orders.order_date
FROM suppliers
INNER JOIN orders
ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id;
```

but I would also like to add another condition, that must be met, e.g. that the suppliers.order_date must equal orders.order_date.

Something like
    ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id AND suppliers.order_date = orders.order_date

How would I get that result? I have spent about an hour searching and it is getting late here now so I try to seek help here....  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do that part in the WHERE, not the JOIN.

Comment: Why not just AND the JOIN condition? It's perfectly valid

Comment: What have you spent hours searching for? Your "something like" is exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_id, suppliers.supplier_name, orders.order_date
FROM suppliers
INNER JOIN orders
ON suppliers.supplier_id = orders.supplier_id
WHERE suppliers.order_date=orders.order_date;
```

Comment: also, as @Felipe said: you can also say "ON id=id AND order_date=order_date"